# "Insert code... " option disabled

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.4, and I'm writing some php code like

```
<?php 

  class consultaDeuda
  { 
      private $tipoIdentifMensaje;
      private $bitPrimario;
      private $bitSecundario;
      private $numTarjeta;
  }

?>
```

When I try to generate getters and setters the option doesn't appear, and the "Insert Code... " option is disabled (in the source menu)

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**: I created a PHP project from the code I was editing. Now the "Insert code..." option is there, but still don't get getters and setters. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have to put some spaces below the attributes of the class for the getter/setter functionality to work. You put some spaces, and in the section below the attributes you put "Insert code..." and it will appear.

Additionally, I also tried this in Sublime Text 2, and works the same way. Just that, when you install snippets or things like that you have to restart Sublime, and then try it the same way. Works fine.